# Parsing the host of a URI in Java when it contains umlauts

Tags: java, uri

I'm trying to parse the host from a URI containing the character 'ü' in the host like this:

```
String host = new java.net.URI("http://füllmethodentafel.de").getHost();
```

However, the host will be null. It works with other URIs. Any ideas why it doesn't work?

Comment: I don't think so. What about http://www.übersetzungsbüro.de or http://füllmethodentafel.de which both work (and you can register such URLs which became possible some years ago)

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ [Yes, it is](http://www.domainnameshop.com/faq.cgi?id=8&session=106ee5e67d523298).

Comment: Are you sure that this site actually exists? I can't see nor ping it from my pc (tried with terminal ping, google chrome, firefox and opera, they all said the url cannot be resolved).

Comment: I think you have to escape it: [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) "The single-argument constructor requires any illegal characters in its argument to be quoted and preserves any escaped octets and other characters that are present"

Comment: Yes, both of them exist. It works in my browser (chrome).

Comment: @lex82 I'm talking about the url you wrote in the question. I can reach and see correctly the two urls posted in comments. I can't see the one written in the question, are you 100% sure it exists? (Also a [whois lookup](http://whois.domaintools.com/xn--hostwith-e6a.com) shows that `http://www.hostwithü.com` was *never* registered)

Comment: It's hard to encode only the special chars in the host when you cannot parse the host fragment ;-) I don't want to encode any slashes or colons in the url. And I'd also like to get the unencoded host since need to compare it to domains in a list.

Comment: The url in the question is an example I made up. I will replace it with one of the working examples to avoid confusion. URI -- in contrast to URL -- does not try to access the uri but only parses characters.

Comment: Have you tried `URI.create(String)` or one of the multi-arg ctors? And finally have you tried URLEncoder? Just out of curiosity?

Comment: same problem for URI.create(), it's only a wrapper for the constructor.  For the other constructors I need to know the parts of the URL that I'm trying to parse.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`java.net.URI`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) can only parse URLs that conform to [RFC 2396](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt). This RFC requires these rules:

```
  hostport      = host [ ":" port ]
  host          = hostname | IPv4address
  hostname      = *( domainlabel "." ) toplabel [ "." ]
  domainlabel   = alphanum | alphanum *( alphanum | "-" ) alphanum
  toplabel      = alpha | alpha *( alphanum | "-" ) alphanum
```

where `alphanum` basically is `[a-zA-Z0-9]`. **Characters like `ü` are not included.**

`URI` *can* handle [`Punycode`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode) URLs like `http://www.xn--hostwith-e6a.com/` which is equivalent to  `http://www.hostwithü.com/`. For this, [`java.net.IDN`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/IDN.html) is useful.

```
String host = "www.hostwithü.com";
String toASCII = IDN.toASCII(host);
System.out.println(toASCII);
// www.xn--hostwith-e6a.com
```

Comment: Using a different constructor like `URI(scheme, host, path, fragment)` will actually result in an `URISyntaxException` indicating that a forbidden character in violation of RFC 2396 was used. Strangely the `URI(str)` constructor doesn't throw the exception although the throw is declared. This seems inconsistent to me.

Comment: @Sebastian_H That is true. Especially since the JavaDoc of `URI(String)` says: '@throws  URISyntaxException If the given string violates RFC 2396, as augmented by the above deviations'.

Comment: Perfect answer, thanks! The behaviour of URI seems indeed inconsistent. getAuthority() works, so I can use it to strip off the username and port by finding : and @ in the string...